# Some question about symplectic transformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I read Arnold's book **Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics** and come across with [three problems in page 229](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=Pd8-s6rOt_cC&pg=PA229&lpg=PA229&dq=be+simple+(multiplicity+1)+eigenvalues+of+a+symplectic+transformation&source=bl&ots=uKsjzFCKMv&sig=hZCx5PXi5gw6kWt2ZUnxwKtKoDM&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=ikpSU8SrJYLliAeHvIHYBA&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=be%20simple%20(multiplicity%201)%20eigenvalues%20of%20a%20symplectic%20transformation&f=false).

> 1.Let $\lambda$ and $\bar{\lambda}$ be simple (multiplicity 1) eigenvalues of a symplectic transformation $S$ with $|\lambda|=1$. Show that the two-dimensional invariant plane $\pi_\lambda$ corresponding to $\lambda,\bar{\lambda}$ is nonnull.
>
> 2.Let $\xi$ be a real vector of plane $\pi_\lambda$, where $Im~\lambda > 0$ and $|\lambda| = 1$. The eigenvalue $\lambda$ is called positive if $[S\xi,\xi] > 0$. Show that this definition does not depend on the choice of $\xi \neq 0$ in the plane $\pi_\lambda$.
>
> 3.Show that $S$ is strong stable if and only if all the eigenvalues $\lambda$ lie on the unit circle and are of definite sign.

In my opinion, it will be difficult to deal with these question with the knowledge in this book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.Since $[,]$ is non-degenerate, there should be such an eigenvector $\eta$  corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda'$ for the eigenvector $\xi$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ that $[\xi, \eta] \neq 0$, which is possible only if $\lambda' = \bar{\lambda}$. Thus, the two-dimensional invariant plane $\pi_\lambda$ is nonnull.

2.Since $\xi$ is a real vector, there is a number $a$ such that $\xi = a\xi_1 + \bar{a}\xi_1$, where $\xi_1$ is the eigenvector with the eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then
$$
[S(a\xi_1 + \bar{a}\bar{\xi}_1), a\xi_1 + \bar{a}\bar{\xi}_1] = (\lambda - \bar{\lambda}) |a|^2 [\xi_1, \bar{\xi}_1] = (2|a|^2 Im \lambda) i(I\xi_1, \xi_1),
$$
the sign of which is independent of $a$, i.e. independent of $\xi$. Note that $i(I\xi_1, \xi_1)$ is a real number.

3.Denote $(G\xi,\xi) = i(I\xi_1, \xi_1)$, and denote $S$ by $M$. 
Assume $M$ is stable and all its eigenvalues are Krein-definite. If $M$ is not strongly stable, there would be $\{M_n\}$ of unstable symplectic matrices converging to $M$. Either $M_n$ has eigenvalue outside the unit circle, or $M_n$ has an eigenvalue on the unit circle which is not semi-simple. Thus, there is a $G$-isotropic unit eigenvector $x_n$:
$$M_n x_n = \lambda_n x_n,~(Gx_n, x_n) = 0.$$
Since $\lambda_n$ is a root of $|M_n - z I|$, we can extract from the sequence $\lambda_n$ a subsequence converging to a root of $M - zI$, i.e. $x_n \rightarrow x, \lambda_n \rightarrow \lambda$. Then $(Gx,x) = 0$ which is impossible since all eigenvalues of $M$ is Krein-definite.

Conversely, assume $M$ is strongly stable. Then all the eigenvalues of $M$ lie on the circle and are semi-simple. For every eigenvalue $\lambda$ with positive imaginary part, we can choose in the eigenspace $Ker(M-\lambda I)$ a $G$-orthogonal basis, say $[\xi_1, \cdots, \xi_m]$ with $(G\xi_k,\xi_k) = \pm 1$. We can take $[\bar{\xi_1},\cdots,\bar{\xi_m}]$ as a basis for the conjugate eigenspace $Ker(M-\bar{\lambda} I)$. If $\pm 1$ is an eigenvalue, the corresponding eigenspace is real and even-dimensional; we can choose its $G$-orthogonal basis to be $[\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_m,\bar{\xi_1},\cdots,\bar{\xi_m}]$ with $(G\xi_k,\xi_k)=1=-(G\bar{\xi}_k,\bar{\xi}_k)$. Putting everything together, we get a $G$-orthonogonal basis of eigenvectors of  $[\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_n,\bar{\xi}_1,\cdots,\bar{\xi}_n]$ for $C^{2n}$. We have $(G\xi_k,\xi_k)=-(G\bar{\xi}_k,\bar{\xi}_k)$, aand by rearranging the basis, we can assume that $(G\xi_k,\xi_k)=1$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$.

Assume there is an eigenvalue $\lambda$ which is not definite. It must have two eigenvectors with opssite $G$-norms, say $\xi_1$ and $\bar{\xi}_1$ if $\lambda = \pm 1$, and $\xi_1, \xi_2$ if $\lambda \neq \pm 1$. Define a linear transformation $M_\tau$ by setting :
$$
M_\tau \xi_1 = \lambda(\xi_1 cosh\tau + \bar{\xi}_1 sinh\tau), M_\tau \bar{\xi}_1 = \lambda(\xi_1 sinh\tau + \bar{\xi}_1 cosh\tau),
$$
if $\lambda = \pm 1$, and 
$$
M_\tau \xi_1 = \lambda(\xi_1 cosh\tau + \xi_2 sinh\tau), M_\tau \xi_2= \lambda(\xi_1 sinh\tau + \xi_2 cosh\tau),
$$
if $\lambda \neq \pm 1$, and $M_\tau = M$ on the invariant subspace generated by the other $\xi_k$.

By construction, $M_\tau$ is real (i.e. $M_\tau R^{2n} \subset R^{2n}$), and symplectic as we readily check. On the other hand $\xi_1 + \bar{\xi}_1$ (if $\lambda = \pm 1$) or $\xi_1 + \xi_2$ (if $\lambda \neq \pm 1$) is an eigenvector of $M_\tau$ with the eigenvalue $\lambda e^\tau$, which is outside the unit circle if $\tau > 0$. So $M_\tau$ is not stable, and $M_\tau \rightarrow M$ when $\tau \rightarrow 0$. This contradicts the fact that $M$ is strongly stable.

> Ref:
>
> 1. Arnold's 'Mathematical methods of classical mechanics' section 42.
> 2. Ivar Ekeland's 'Convexity methods in Hamiltonian mechanics' chapter 1.